# Alert dialog in JavaFX 2 - too many touch points reported

Tags: java, touch, javafx-2

I have a fullscreen main scene.
Then I have an alert dialog which extends Stage. It's filled with custom text, positioned on a screen and showed.

Problem is that when I touch my screen, this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Too many touch points reported
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.touchEventNext(Scene.java:2626)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$10.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:985)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$10.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:964)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleNextTouchEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:964)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleNextTouchEvent(View.java:549)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyNextTouchEvent(View.java:1004)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.TouchInputSupport.notifyNextTouchEvent(TouchInputSupport.java:117)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinGestureSupport.notifyNextTouchEvent(WinGestureSupport.java:58)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Everything is working but this error shows then during all touch events.

How should I properly implement an alert dialog?
Thanks.

Implementation of an alert dialog is this one - http://tech.chitgoks.com/2013/06/19/how-to-create-alert-dialog-like-joptionpane-in-java-fx-2/ .

Answer (score 0):

This code in the link you have shared, does not work as it is. It throws compilation error.
Its working fine for me after making the below changes.

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            AlertDialog.this.close();
        }
    });
```

to

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
             AlertDialog.this.close();
        }
    });
```

and changing the code section below

```
if (width &lt; WIDTH_DEFAULT)
        width = WIDTH_DEFAULT;
```

to

```
if (width < WIDTH_DEFAULT)
  width = WIDTH_DEFAULT;
```

Let me know after making those changes, if it works for you. I am assuming you must have set the owner stage properly.

Comment: I have not tested this piece of code on a touch based device though. Is your problem specific to touch sensitive device ?

Comment: Thanks. I think this error is not related to dialog, but generally to JavaFX - see https://forum.java.sun.com/thread/2604792 .

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update to java 9(where the issue resolved) you can try use reflaction on the touchPoint array in the Scene class,  reset it once the exception is thrown and also the other fields that is related in the Scene class, it worked for me. You will also need a try catch block on the entire app though to catch the Runtime exception.